# Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, assemblies, mixed-mode

I'm trying to make a simple video player so i wont to use

Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll

but when i'm using this dll file programe raise this error

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

before the open file dialog appear 
in this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int width = this.panel1.Width,
        height= this.panel1.Height;

    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.ShowDialog();

    ss = new Video(open.FileName, false);

    ss.Owner = panel1;
    ss.Size = new Size(width, height);

    ss.Play();
    ss.Stop();
}
```

I'm searching about this and I found some solutions on StackOverflow:

1. [Mixed Mode Error when building in Release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159776/mixed-mode-error-when-building-in-release-mode)
2. [Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641006/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322-of-the-runtime-and-cann)
3. [Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322)

But I don't know how to fix this error so any one have another solution or can explain any one of these. If it required editing a file, please let me know where this file is located.

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the App.config of your application. 
It should contain the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/> 
  </startup> 
</configuration>
```

This information appears in the links you provided.

Comment: Where i can find App.config file.
can you give me the path

Comment: It should be in your Windows Application Project.. if it somehow doesn't exist there you can always add it yourself. Just create a file by that name, place it in your project's root folder and paste the XML above.